# Amazingly, Json DateTime with seconds lost Seconds after de-serializing on WCF service

Tags: c#, json, wcf, datetime, deserialization

I post(using jQuery $.post) the following json DateTime to a WCF service(using C#):

```
"/Date(1331713200000)/"
```

On Firebug CommandLine, I test it:

```
Date(1331713200000)
```

This is the output:
"Wed Mar 14 2012 11:52:06 GMT+0330"

On server side, I've break point on Service Input argument (which is System.DateTime). What is received is the posted date time without Seconds!

```
{3/14/2012 11:50:00 AM}
```

Did you ever try this? What's wrong?

Comment: it also lost two minutes somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date(1331713200000)` is returning *now*, the argument is ignored.  `new Date(1331713200000)` is what you should be calling.  As Jon has said - the time you're getting server-side is correct.

Comment: You are right Andras, as Jon said, `Either you're using Firebug incorrectly, or it's in error.` and I found out that ` I should new Date(1331713200000) instead of Date(1331713200000)`

Answer (score 2):

Either you're using Firebug incorrectly, or it's in error. Look at your number, which is meant to be the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch. Let's divide by 1000 so it ends up being the number of *seconds*: 1331713200

How would that end up with the number "6" at the end in any way, shape or form?

In fact, we can divide that number by 60 and get a whole number... which entirely in line with the value you've seen on the server side.

The value 1331713200000 *does* represent 2012-03-14T08:20:00Z.

Comment: right, Jon. I should `new Date(1331713200000)` instead of Date(1331713200000)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these posts will help you out:

[Send JQuery JSON to WCF REST using date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474352/send-jquery-json-to-wcf-rest-using-date)

http://skysanders.net/subtext/archive/2010/02/18/wcf-to-json-dates-and-back-again.aspx

The combination of client dates and WCF don't work well together.