# Angular - WCF RESTfull service - send DateTime

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, angularjs

I have such a method in my WCF REST-full service

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public EventData NewEvent(EventData ev)
        {
            _logger.Info("Save event method called. EventName: " + ev.name);

            return ev;
        }
```

I'm trying to call it from an Angular service

```
save: function(event){
            var def = $q.defer();
            $resource('http://localhost/EventRegistration/WebServices/Data.svc/newevent')
                .save(event,
                function(response){def.resolve(response);},
                function(response){def.reject(response)});

            return def.promise ;
        }
```

in fiddler I do see that such a JSON is being send to my WCF method

```
{"name":"gfdfg","date":"11/11/2011","time":"3546","location":{"address":"2345","city":"3245","province":"2345"}}
```

for which my service failes to execute with such an error

```
<p>The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'There was an error deserializing the object of type EventRegistration.Models.EventData. DateTime content '11/11/2011' does not start with '\/Date(' and end with ')\/' as required for JSON.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: </p>
      <p>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterDataContractMessageFormatter.ReadObject(Message message)
```

so, the question is, how do I instruct Angular to format the datetime objects into something consumable by my WCF REST service?

Answer (score 2):

I did solve this by adding such a method to app.js in my AngularJS application

```
Date.prototype.toMSJSON = function () {
    var date = '/Date(' + this.getTime() + ')/'; //CHANGED LINE
    return date;
};
```

and then before calling my REST service I added such a call

```
save: function(event){
            var def = $q.defer();

            event.date = (new Date(event.date)).toMSJSON(); // !!!convert to REST format

            $resource('http://localhost/EventRegistration/WebServices/Data.svc/newevent')
                .save(event,
                function(response){def.resolve(response);},
                function(response){def.reject(response)});

            return def.promise ;
        }
```

not sure if this is the best solution, but seems to work.

Comment: If you are going to copy code verbatim, shouldn't you at least reference the source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474352/send-jquery-json-to-wcf-rest-using-date/5310986#5310986