# The best way how to pass datetime from javascript to WCF

Tags: javascript, c#, rest, wcf, datetime

I have question what is the best way to pass DateTime from WCF to JS and back? I'm currently work with ordinary WCF where I have defined DataContract for model where I had a lot of properties of types like DateTime, string, int, etc. When I call this service I take JSON object with Date like this "/Date(firstNum+secondNum)"

For parse date I'm using this function

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
```

And it is OK. Date is identical with my DateTime object which I passed from WCF.

Problem is when i want to pass this Date to WCF. I'm using ajax

```
   $.ajax({
    type: POST,
    url: "myserviceUrl",
    data: JSON.stringfy({myDate: $("#mypicker").val()}), //for example 24.3.2000 0:00:00
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: json,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    },
    error: funstion(e) {}
});
```

I pass "24.3.2000 0:00:00" but in WCF I take datetime with timestamp like "23.3.2000 23:00:00" and I do not know why :/ ... any ideas please?

Comment: [Send JQuery JSON to WCF REST using date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474352/send-jquery-json-to-wcf-rest-using-date) This solution help me. Thanks for answers

Comment: I use moment,js,: http://momentjs.com/